# Minimum cost to make all array elements zero

Tags: dynamic-programming

Minimum cost to make all array elements zero So the operations are as following :

A subarray of array A is a segment od contiguous elements in array A. Given an array A of N elements, you can apply the following operations as many times as you like :

Operation 1: Choose any subarray [L,R] and decrement every element in this subarray for a cost C1 Operation 2: Choose an index I such that A[i] is positive and setting A[i] = 0. The cost of this operation is C2

Our task is to find the minimum cost for making all the elements zero.

```
1 <= C1 <= 10 
1 <= C2 <= 10^4
1 <= A[i] <= 10^8
```

Comment: You better formulate a consistent question post rather than vary between minimum number of operations and minimum cost.

Comment: @sri Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: @sri - It should be made clear whether A[i] are allowed to decrement below zero.

Comment: @Armali It can be, but it is meaningless to do so because if any `A[i] < 0`, it can no longer be `0` again.

Comment: Ah, you are right - I misread _such that A[i] is positive_ as it'd read _such that i is positive_.

Answer (score 1):

I will describe a divide-and-conquer algorithm here.

### Idea

Notice that when we have an array, it is always optimal to do all Operation 1 before any Operation 2. Why? When you do Operation 2, for example on the array `[1, 1, 3, 4]`, say you set the 3rd element as 0, it will make the array `[1, 1, 0, 4]`. Previously in the array `[1, 1, 3, 4]` we can do Operation 1 on interval `[0, 3]`, but now we need two operations to do the same thing (i.e. `[0, 1]` and `[3, 3]`). As a result, it is always optimal to do all Operation 1 before any Operation 2.

Also, we notice that when we do Operation 1, we always do so such that some element will reach `0`, otherwise it would be meaningless to do Operation 1. This yields a divide-and-conquer algorithm which I will illustrate with an example:

### Implementation

Assume the array is `[8, 4, 3, 6, 7, 9, 12, 5]`. We call a recursive function `solve(0, 7)` which will return the cost to make all elements 0.

In `solve(0, 7)`, we have two choices:

1. Apply Operation 1 for three times on `[0, 7]`, it would reduce the array to `[5, 1, 0, 3, 4, 6, 9, 2]`, taking a cost of `3 * C1`. Then recursively solve for `solve(0, 1)` and `solve(3, 7)`. The answer would be `3 * C1 + solve(0, 1) + solve(3, 7)`.
2. Apply Operation 2 on all elements. This will give a cost of `(7 - 0 + 1) * C2 = 8 * C2`.

We take whichever way resulting in a smaller cost.