# Find minimum operations that make the array 0

Tags: dynamic-programming

Consider an array `a` of positive integers  `1 <= a[i] <= 10^9`

We can perform an operation on this array which involves taking any integer `x` and subtracting or adding it to a subarray of `a`

The goal is to make the entire array 0

Some examples:

`2 1 2 1  =>  1 0 1 0  =>  0 0 1 0  =>  0 0 0 0`

This requires 3 operations. First subtract 1 from all the elements (subarray=`a[0..3]`), then individually subtract 1 from single element subarrays (`a[0..0], a[2..2]`)

Alternative way could've been:

```
2 1 2 1  =>  2 1 1 0  =>  2 0 0 0  =>  0 0 0 0

                      =>  1 0 0 0  =>  0 0 0 0
```

Example 2:

`4 6 2  =>  0 2 2  => 0 0 0`

Example 3:

`10 3 2 9  =>  10 10 9 9  =>  0 0 9 9  =>  0 0 0 0`

I searched a lot, not able to find the exact problem statement. The solution that I came across though (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68789827/4014182) talks about a divide and conquer solution wherein you realize that every time there is a 0 in the array, you can "split" the array. But how to get that 0 in the first place is beyond my understanding.